# Use Azure Active Directory B2C without migrating users

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have a client that currently use a ERP-system to store all their clients. This is a closed source ERP so they can not change the authentication flow. Right now they have an authentication API that various other APIs use but development is slow. They are now facing a challenge in that they need to bring more systems in and given the current structure this takes time since their APIs are tightly coupled with the rest of the systems. They absolutely wan't to avoid other departments from creating applications with their own authentication simply because they cannot keep their pace up.

They wan't to keep SSO for all their customer systems but have better control which users are allowed to do what.

I have been reading about Azure Active Directory B2C and it seems really great. We use Azure Active Directory (AAD) authentication for our internal applications and it works flawlessly most of the time.

Here comes the two part question:

1. Is it possible to use `Azure AD B2C` and still keep users in the ERP? For example if we can connect `Azure AD B2C` to send a request to a service that responds with user data if that user exists given that the credentials are correct.
2. Extension of question 1. The current ERP-systems gives the user an access token and refresh token. Is it still possible to use Azure Active Directory B2C in this case? Basically add our own Identity Provider that will refresh the access token when needed. Is this a feasible thing to do and are there any guides in creating this? Perhaps IdentityServer4 could be used or can it be simplified? http://openid.net/developers/certified/#OPLibs https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4

Given these words on their website I think it should work:

> Support all platforms and open standards

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. As Miroslav mentions, you should use [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom). This requires a ramp up on custom policies which can have a steep learning curve, but essentially you would take the starterpack (see [getting started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom)) and you would modify the userjourney to not write to the B2C directory (basically remove this step). Instead, you would do a call out to wherever the users are. This call out can either be an OIDC identity provider or a REST API, which are specified using technical profiles.

Comment: Thanks! Can custom policies handle refreshing tokens as well? If yes are there any code examples for this?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Refreshing a token for what?

Comment: Can Azure AD B2C handle refreshing access tokens or does that have to be done on the application level?

Comment: Azure AD B2C is a token issuer, meaning it can issue refresh tokens. To use a refresh token to get a new id or access token, the application needs to make a call to Azure AD B2C. In other words, refreshing a token is done at the application level because the application needs to make a request.